# Generalise methods on Zipper with different types for current element and left/right lists

Tags: class, haskell, zipper

I'm toying around with zippers, where the current element can have a different type than the left and right lists:

```
data Z a b = Z ([a], b, [a])
```

One can navigate the zipper with `moveLeft` and `moveRight`:

```
moveLeft  :: (b -> a -> a) -> (a -> b -> b) -> Z a b -> Z a b
moveLeft listF currentF (Z (x:xs, c, ys)) = Z (xs, g x c, ((f c x):ys))

moveRight :: (b -> a -> a) -> (a -> b -> b) -> Z a b -> Z a b
moveRight listF currentF (Z (xs, c, y:ys)) = Z (((f c y):xs), g y c, ys)
```

Here, `listF` transforms a list element and the current one into a list element to the left or right. `currentF` transforms the current element and a list element into the current element.

If both the current and the list type are equal, moving is simple:

```
moveLeftSameType :: Z a a -> Z a a
moveLeftSameType = moveLeft const const
```

and everything works as expected, nice!

What I'd like to do now is to generalize the above idea, such that by only implementing the `listF` and `currentF` functions for a given `Z a b` (say `a :: Char`, `b :: Int`), `moveLeft` and `moveRight` do the right thing automagically. What would be the correct way to do this?

*Remark*

I have tried to implement a class like this:

```
class CPos a where
    listF :: c -> d -> d
    currentF :: d -> c -> c
    moveLeft :: a -> a
    moveRight :: a -> a
```

where `moveLeft/Right` are implemented in terms of `listF` and `currentF`, but this fails with

```
The class method `listF' mentions none of the type variables of the class CPos a
```

*Remark 2*

Something I don't like about the above idea in general is the fact that be allowing arbitrary functions `listF` and `currentF` it's impossible to guarantee

```
moveLeft . moveRight = id
```

(if the zipper is within the list, on the borders this doesn't hold anyways). Any hints to enforce this?

Comment: Re your second remark: document it as a “CPos law”. c.f. [Functor laws](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Functor.html#t:Functor), [Monoid laws](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to that.

```
class CPos a b where
    listF :: b -> a -> a
    currentF :: a -> b -> b
    moveLeft :: Z a b -> Z a b
    moveLeft (Z (x:xs, c, ys)) = Z (xs, currentF x c, ((listF c x):ys))
    moveRight :: Z a b -> Z a b
    moveRight (Z (xs, c, y:ys)) = Z (((listF c y):xs), currentF y c, ys)
```

I don't think you can enforce `moveLeft . moveRight = id`. I mean it is undecidable to guarantee two functions are equal. The best you can do is to write `quickcheck` testcases to guarantee the same.